# Postman Json Schema validation failed

Tags: json, api, automated-tests, postman

I have this little issue. I am building API tests with postman.
One of my tests want to validate a Json response.

This is the kind of response that I have received:

```
       {
        "comuni": [
         {
        "istat": "015002",
        "code": "A010",
        "comune": "ABBIATEGRASSO",
        "provincia": "MI",
        "cap": "20081",
        "latitude": 45.393036,
        "longitude": 8.919824,
        "soppresso": false,
        "regione": "Lombardia",
        "parte_italia": "nord",
        "is_provincia": 0,
        "nome_provincia": "Milano"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ]};
```

So I receive an array of objects like this one above.
This is the test that I wrote:

```
            var schema = {
            "comuni" :
         [
            {
                "istat" : {
                    "type" : "Integer"
                },
                "code" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "comune" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "provincia" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "cap" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                },
                "latitude" : {
                    "type": "Number"
                },
                "longitude" : {
                    "type": "Number"
                },
                "soppresso": {
                    "tyoe" : "boolean"
                },
                "regione" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "parte_italia": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "is_provincia": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "nome_provincia": {
                    "type": "string"
                }

    }]
}

pm.test("JSON schema validation", function() {
  var paperwork = pm.response.json();
  var result = tv4.validate(paperwork, schema, false, true);
  if (result !== true) {
      console.log('Schema validation failed:', tv4.error);
  }
  /*console.log(tv4.error.dataPath);*/
  pm.expect(result).to.be.true;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

But the test fails:

> Schema validation failed: unknown property (not in schema)

Obviously I am doing something wrong with the schema, but I do not understand what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is incorrect. It should be like this.

```
{
 "description": "Any validation failures are shown in the right-hand Messages pane.",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
 "foo": {
  "type": "number"
},
"bar": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
    ]
 }
 }
}
```

And data should look like,

```
{
"foo": 12345,
"bar": "a"
}
```

Refer below link for more [examples](http://json-schema.org/example1.html), like Array/Objects etc.

Comment: no, i didn't write the final ]} because i wrote only the first object.the result is "comuni" which is an array of objects like the one that you can see above

Comment: when you say, you didn't write ]}, what exactly you mean? is it there in your data but you didn't put in your original question?

Comment: Your schema defination is not correct as per version json-schema4.0, that POSTMAN uses. I'll be modifying my above answer and try to modify your schema, it should work.